# HorizontalPager

Tags: android

Hi i've just implemented a horizontal scroll for my android application,according to some excellent sample code that i received from [here](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager) my only problem is that I'm swipping through TextViews what I actually wanna do is swipe through activities.As you will see through the link i provided the TextViews are defined in the .xml file from the horizontalpager so scrolling through them is done quite automatically.How can i achieve the same results but this time with activities?

Comment: Read about Fragments in android

Comment: My question maybe wasnt clear.As I said I've already implemented this using horizontalPager and i can swipe through plain views.Is there a way i can do the same without changing much thinks the way they are now?Or it need to be written from the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activities arent Views so no way and no good idea anyway!

But what you wanna do can be done with a ViewPager and Fragments!

Fragments: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

ViewPager: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Edit: Here would be the Adapter you would wanna use: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi i came accross to an excellent blog explaining very explicitly the above and also providing some sample code so i'll post [it](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/) just in case any one stumbles upon the same problem as me, note: that's a link for quick downloading of the [sample](https://github.com/mitchwongho/Andy.git)